# If X is an exponential random variable with parameter lambda and x>0...

Tags: probability

If $X$ is an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$, and $c>0$, show $cX$ is exponential with parameter $\frac{\lambda}{c}$.

I don't remember being taught this in class, nor does anybody in my class. I found a solution online but it seems complicated and uses notation that I've never seen in my textbook.

Comment: This does not make sense as stated. A **general** random variable has no "parameter"... What distribution do you assume on $X$?

Comment: Apologies @ClementC. Had forgotten to define the random variable. Fixed it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a\geq0$ ; we have
 $$\mathbb{P}\left[cX\leq a\right]
 =\mathbb{P}\left[X\leq \frac{a}{c}\right]
 =1-e^{-\lambda\frac{a}{c}}$$
 then $cX$ is exponential with parameter $\frac{\lambda}{c}$.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about [characteristic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)? If so, for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$,

$$
 \mathbb{E} e^{it\cdot cX} = \mathbb{E} e^{i(ct)X} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{ict}{\lambda}} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{it}{c^{-1}\lambda}}
$$ and the RHS is the characteristic function of an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda^\prime = c^{-1}\lambda$.